# Hide the Edit button in products for specific user group in openerp?

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I need to hide the Edit button in Products page only for a specific user group ("Purchase/User") group. How can I do that?. I tried to change it in view xml (source) file at form level.  However it is not reflecting.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

purchase/user group only has read rights for products. so nothing to change here. if you have a user within this group (and only in this or others without specific product rights) you would see no edit button on products.
problem now is: what about an user in more than one product rights influencing groups? sorry i have no idea :/

Comment: I have tried the access rights also. However it is not working for me.
I have the only one user under purchase user group and he did not assigned to any other group.

Comment: i've tested it on http://runbot.openerp.com (v7 server) and didn't see an edit-button (user demo was set for hr as employee and as purchase user only)

Comment: I resolved the problem. Another group have the same user and also have the write access. That is the problem. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Access Right's of All the Groups and uncheck "Write" option for Product's item. Please check  it only for "Purchase/User" group. Hope this works.